# OpenGL Blending with textures converted from SDL_Surface

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I wanted to try making a game with OpenGL and GLUT, but as it turns out, GLUT is not well adapted to making games. So I switched to using SDL 1.2 (this is for a sort of competition, so I can't use SDL 2). When I saw I could use OpenGL within SDL, I decided to do that, since I had already written a majority of my code with OpenGL. Now, I'm having issues trying to load an image into an `SDL_Surface` and then converting it to an OpenGL texture, with OpenGL blending enabled. Here is the code I'm using (`loadImage` loads an `SDL_Surface` & `loadTexture` loads into an OpenGL texture):

```
SDL_Surface * Graphics::loadImage(const char * filename) {
    SDL_Surface *loaded = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface *optimized = nullptr;

    loaded = IMG_Load(filename);

    if (loaded) {
        optimized = SDL_DisplayFormat(loaded);
        SDL_FreeSurface(loaded);
    }

    return optimized;
}

GLuint Graphics::loadTexture(const char * filename, GLuint oldTexId) {
    //return SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filename, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, oldTexId, SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA);
    GLuint texId = 0;
    SDL_Surface *s = loadImage(filename);
    if (!s) return 0;

    if (oldTexId) glDeleteTextures(1, &oldTexId);

    glGenTextures(1, &texId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

    int format;
    if (s->format->BytesPerPixel == 4) {
        if (s->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
            format = GL_RGBA;
        else
            format = GL_BGRA;
    } else if (s->format->BytesPerPixel == 3) {
        if (s->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else
            format = GL_BGR;
    }

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, s->format->BytesPerPixel, s->w, s->h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, s->pixels);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    SDL_FreeSurface(s);

    return texId;
}
```

I've been searching online for a solution to this issue quite a bit, and none of the solutions I found worked. This code actually works when I don't `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`, but when I do enable it, it doesn't show anything on screen anymore. I am fairly new to OpenGL, and I'm not sure I'm using the `glTexImage2D` correctly.

The way I was loading images before I converted to SDL was using the SOIL library, and when I replace the `loadTexture` function's body with that commented out first line, it actually works fine, but I'd rather have less external libraries, and do everything graphics-side with SDL & OpenGL.

Comment: Why are you using `SDL_DisplayFormat()` if you're just loading the bits into an OpenGL texture?  You only need to optimize surfaces to speed up SDL's blitting system, it has nothing to do with OpenGL.

Comment: @genpfault when I don't `SDL_DisplayFormat()` the surface, `format->BytesPerPixel` is 1. I might modify my function to read that eventually, but for now, it isn't, or at least shouldn't, be an issue

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of glTexImage2D is wrong:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, s->format->BytesPerPixel, s->w, s->h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, s->pixels);
```

The third argument is internalFormat and must be one of the base internal formats:

```
GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT
GL_DEPTH_STENCIL
GL_RED
GL_RG
GL_RGB
GL_RGBA
```

Or one of the sized internal formats, which specifies the bits per channel.

So in other words your third argument should be either:

```
GL_RGB 
GL_RGB8 
GL_RGBA 
GL_RGBA8
```

If you're using an 8 bit per channel texture.

Whereas the 7th argument, format, can be either RGB or BGR, (including the alpha version), the third argument, internalFormat can only be RGB and not the other way around.

So where you check the red mask and change the format is still good for the 7th argument, the third argument (internalFormat) should be either GL_RGB or GL_RGBA. Or optionally the sized version GL_RGB8 or GL_RGBA8.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, /*GL_RGB or GL_RGBA*/, s->w, s->h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, s->pixels);
```

[Docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)

Comment: That didn't fix the issue. It still doesn't appear, but only when blending is enabled

Comment: `glEnable(GL_BLEND); glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`
thats how I enable blending, but it shouldn't change anything, cause it does work with image loaded with SOIL

Comment: @Arthur Bouvier I'm confused by what you're saying.  The final component (w) or (a) of the output of the fragment shader will be decide the blending. Make it 1 and see if it draws. Then if what you say worked with SOIL but not with SDL then make sure you're not getting the wrong alpha mask. For example in your fragment shader the sampler will return a vec4.  Try moving the r, g, b, a components to the last (w) component of the vec4 written out and see whether channels are mixed up.

Comment: @Arthur Bouvier Or make a png or jpg that's completely black with an alpha of 255, load and sample from it in your fragment shader with alpha blending on, if it draws nothing make the w component 1 and if it draws red or blue then you know you need to sort out the proper channel order.  Or make a red image and after loading it with SDL loop through and print each byte as an unsigned char cast to an int to see where red is. There's lots of ways to figure out problems.

Comment: when I was stepping through with my debugger, I checked the Amask and Ashift on the surface format and both were zero (Bshift is also zero btw)

Comment: also, I have no idea what you mean by "fragment shader", I'm completely new to OpenGL, and I haven't learned anything about shaders yet